# Как работать с Localstorage и Nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, auth, localstorage, nuxt.js

Всем привет. 
Есть такая библиотека:
https://auth.nuxtjs.org/getting-starterd/setup
(на странице объясняется как правильно ее подключить.)


Мне ее порекомендовали для работы с localstorage.
Подключаю ее следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]


[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И у меня ничего не работает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]


[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если подключатся к localstorage например через чистый js
(как это показано на втором скрине(с зеленой стрелкой код закоментированный))
 - то все прекрасно работает.


Вопрос:
Что я делаю не правильно при подключении библиотеки или что я упускаю из виду?


P.S. Если кому то нужен код подключения не в виде скриншота то вот он:

```
 modules: [
      '@nuxtjs/axios',
      '@nuxtjs/auth'
  ],
  auth: {
      // Options
  },


  created() {
      let key = 'db';
      let val = 'value';
      //localStorage.setItem(key, val);
      this.$auth.$storage.getLocalstorage( key );
  },
```

Comment: А вы собственно, библиотеку установили `npm install @nuxtjs/auth @nuxtjs/axios`?

Comment: да, конечно.
Установил.

Comment: Тогда объясняйте подробнее - что значит *И у меня ничего не работает*. С указанием ошибки, если есть, поведения, что должно работать и как работает. Приветствуется информация, добавленная в вопрос, а не в комментарии.

Comment: Добавил скрин с ошибкой.

Comment: А вы его в компоненте подключили вот так `middleware: ['auth'],`?

Comment: И вот это сделали? *When adding auth-module to a new Nuxt project ensure you have activated the Vuex store. More information on how to do that can be found on the Nuxt Getting Started Guide.*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использовать целый модуль авторизации только из-за доступа к localStorage не лучшая идея.

И что-то мне подсказывает что на ssr на сервере никак не сделаешь localStorage, localStorage только на клиенте, на сервере никак не будет работать.  Поэтому удобно хранить в куках, доступно и там и там.

Поэтому в nuxt-auth `this.$auth.$storage.getLocalstorage(key)` у вас и не работает, `created` это hook жизненного цикла который выполняется на сервере, не смогло найти localStorage и выдало ошибку.

Comment: А какой хук жизненного цикла вы рекомендуете прописывать в данном случае?

Comment: Пользуйтесь браузерным localStorage, вам не нужна никакя библиотека, и можете и в created прописать если сделаете проверку что это клиент: `if (process.browser)`. created выполняется и на клиенте и сервере. nuxt основан на vue-server-renderer, вот что написано  про хуки жизненого цикла в документации: [ссылка](https://ssr.vuejs.org/ru/guide/universal.html#%D1%85%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BAn%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0)

Comment: Такой вопрос:
Можно ли каким то образом сделать LocalStorage реактивным?
(Или Vuex)
+ может ли реактивную связь поддерживать Vuex c localStorage?

Comment: Это уже другая тема, можете попробовать [это](https://github.com/ropbla9/vue-reactive-storage).

Comment: Еще 1 вопрос: при подключении модуля ссылку на который вы скинули используется следующая команда: Vue.use  - в случае если у меня Nuxt.js я так понимаю это работать не будет? (если нет - то что необходимо прописать?)
(по крайней мере пока что не работает.)

Comment: на серверной части не будет работать, надо использовать inject: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins#inject-in-root-amp-context